# Is it possible to turn on debug logging for a specific mojo or goal?

Tags: maven

I'm attempting to debug a particular Maven goal execution during my build. I know that I can use -X to get all debug logs, but this creates a deluge of information that is not useful to me.

Is there a way to target -X to a particular plugin/goal/execution?